# Identify older than 1995 (probably) sci-fi movie with an alien referred to as Xenomorph

Tags: story-identification

I watched this as a teen, so it is probably dated before 1995.
If I remember correctly, one of the initial scenes was set on a space-ship and there were some heavy vault-like doors. I believe some kind of accident causes at least one of the sealed doors to open and an alien breaks free. Somehow, the alien (if my memory serves me right it was just referred to as a "Xenomorph" later) gets to Earth and thats where most part of the movie happened. Most likely it was "present" Earth, no future setting.

Comment: The creature in the [Alien franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)) is called a Xenomorph.

Comment: Yes but it had definitely nothing to do with that franchise. It was a different style and much more B-Movie like. Really hard to remember after such a long time.

Comment: The later movies were definitely B-like. Part of that was Whedon's shitty writing, part of it was the studio just shoveling it all through without anything resembling  good taste or quality, part of that was stars like Weaver demanding ridiculous constraints (no guns).

Comment: Was this a TV movie or theater run?  If T.V. it could be the T.V. Miniseries (later series) called "Something is Out There."  The description at IMDB is:   Two police officers investigate a series of brutal murders in which the victims have had bodily organs removed. When one of them questions a young woman who has been seen at the crime scenes, it turns out she is an alien from an interstellar prison ship and that the murders have been committed by a powerful xenomorphic alien which had escaped.   If I remember correctly the opening scene shows the alien escaping from the prison ship.

Comment: @beichst: Dude, you got it. Thanks to your pointer i watched part 1 of "Something is Out There" on Youtube and there is was at [46:15](http://youtu.be/kjjD4lEpY48?t=46m50s). Exactly that scene was in my mind. Oh those memories... No clue if the miniseries is actually good, but i will give it a try now :) Thank you so much! If you convert this into an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: I remember several movies with the "bad aliens on earth chased by alien bounty hunters" theme from this period, but the only one I can remember the title to off hand is "Critters".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the T.V. Miniseries (later series) called [*Something is Out There*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Is_Out_There).

The [description at IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096134/plotsummary) is:

> Two police officers investigate a series of brutal murders in which the victims have had bodily organs removed. When one of them questions a young woman who has been seen at the crime scenes, it turns out she is an alien from an interstellar prison ship and that the murders have been committed by a powerful xenomorphic alien which had escaped.

The first episode contains the part where the alien is escaping from the prison ship. The scene with the vault-like door that was described [can be watched on Youtube](http://youtu.be/kjjD4lEpY48?t=46m50s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added references to Wikipedia and Youtube and performed some minor improvements.