# Please help identify this 2-part TV movie: Alien woman crash-lands on earth, falls in love, 199x

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

In 1991 or 1992 I saw a two-part (probably made for) TV US movie. It is about an alien starship crash landing on planet Earth (in the USA). An attractive 100% human-looking woman (I believe the only survivor) interacts with our male lead so that they can solve a problem at hand (like communicating with other aliens, or recovering the ship, or working against an alien threat, something like that). She is telepathic and lost her spouse in the space ship wreck (or maybe she just can't ever get back to him because of the broken-down ship?). I remember her flashbacks where she is intimate with her spouse by the touching of hands.

During their time together on earth they fall in love and I believe she stays in the end.

I know this is not much but there aren't that many two-part sci-fi TV movies so someone may remember?

Comment: This exact show has been asked about before.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124739 etc.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55279/38557, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32141, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109750,  and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124739

Comment: @JDługosz Most of those are duped and one of them are duped and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/television-female-time-travel-police-officer) doesn't have a confirmed answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the (short-lived) TV series [Something is Out There](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Is_Out_There).

One of the deuteragonists is a female alien. There's a scene in which she and her alien spouse "kiss" by touching hands. It appears *most pleasurable*...

> Jack Breslin (Joseph Cortese is a police officer investigating brutal
>   murders in which organs have been removed from the victims. He learns
>   that the crimes are being committed by a monstrous alien insectoid
>   prisoner known as a xenomorph, possessing shape-shifting and physical
>   possession abilities, who has escaped from an alien prison starship
>   passing by the solar system, and he teams up with a beautiful medical
>   officer from that ship, Ta'Ra (Maryam d'Abo), to track the villain
>   down. Ta'Ra has assorted superhuman abilities, including telepathy and
>   superhuman agility, which come in handy during the mission.

Comment: Great, that's it, well remembered! Seems I forgot the murdering alien part - but remembered her well.

Comment: Now all I need to know is how to get it legally...

Comment: There were a couple of dupes, so I decided to link them to this one because it seems the most detailed ;)

Comment: NBC miniseries, not a short-lived series.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I found one or two more.

Comment: I loved this show back in the day. Back when the D'abo sisters (cousins?) were nerd hotness :P

Comment: Another one to check out. Nice.