# Looking for the movie with the telepathic female humanoid alien chasing a xenomorph on earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, xenomorph

Sometime in the mid 90's I saw a movie about a female humanoid alien chasing a xenomorph on earth. She teams up with a man who I think is a cop. The woman is telepathic. In a flashback we see her on her spaceship with the rest of her crew. If I remember correctly the xenomorph is also telepathic and takes over a crewmembers mind and escapes to earth.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: Was it specifically a "xenomorph", i.e. from the *Aliens* series?

Comment: How that female humanoid alien looked like?

Comment: Take a look at "Something is Out There "https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159440/please-help-identify-this-2-part-tv-movie-alien-woman-crash-lands-on-earth-fal: "Jack Breslin (Joseph Cortese is a police officer investigating brutal murders in which organs have been removed from the victims. He learns that the crimes are being committed by a monstrous alien insectoid prisoner" (Something is Out There)

Comment: I think it was an "alien shaped monster" of some sort!

The female was a blonde in her thirties I think

Comment: Thank You Yaroslav :-) That's the one!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @PetterFlemberg: You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be [Something Is Out There](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096134/), a TV miniseries from 1998?

From IMDB:

> Two police officers investigate a series of brutal murders in which
> the victims have had bodily organs removed. When one of them questions
> a young woman who has been seen at the crime scenes, it turns out she
> is an alien from an interstellar prison ship and that the murders have
> been committed by a powerful xenomorphic alien which had escaped.

[image]

The entire series is on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRLftmlbLuE).

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Something Is Out There](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Is_Out_There)*** (1988)...?

According to the Wikipedia plot summary, it does involve a police officer teaming up with a telepathic female alien to track down a 'xenomorph' that escaped to Earth from an alien prison ship.

> Jack Breslin (Joseph Cortese) is a police officer investigating brutal murders in which organs have been removed from the victims with (by human standards) surgically impossible speed. He learns that the crimes are being committed by a monstrous alien insectoid prisoner known as a xenomorph, possessing shape-shifting and physical possession abilities, who has escaped from an alien prison starship passing by the solar system, and he teams up with a beautiful medical officer from that ship, Ta'Ra (Maryam d'Abo), to track down the villain. Ta'Ra has assorted superhuman abilities, including telepathy and superhuman agility, which come in handy during the mission.

Answer (score 0):

Partial match would be the 1990 film *[I Come in Peace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Come_in_Peace)*, also released as *Dark Angel*.

> Houston police officer Jack Caine will not let police procedure prevent him from pursuing his mission to wipe out the White Boys, a gang of white collar drug dealers who killed his partner while Caine was stopping a convenience store robbery.
>
> The White Boys disguise their narcotics trafficking behind the visage of expensive luxury sports cars, executive level jobs, and flashy designer suits. Led by the vicious but urbane Victor Manning, the White Boys operate above accusation but not suspicion. When the White Boys steal a shipment of heroin from a federal evidence warehouse, they hide evidence of their involvement by blowing up the facility, killing or injuring numerous people. This brings in the FBI, and Caine is partnered with a by-the-book agent, Arwood "Larry" Smith. They investigate the drug theft and the later murder of several key White Boys soldiers by a hyper fast spinning disk. At the same time, Caine is made aware - via his girlfriend, coroner Diane Pallone - of a series of strange drug-related deaths. The corpses are full of heroin, but the cause of death is a puncture wound to the forehead. Unknown to Caine and the police, the deaths are caused by Talec, an alien who is extracting something from the victims. He is being pursued by Azeck, a similar alien to himself.

One major difference is that the alien is not female, but male, and I don't believe they're revealed to be telepathic.

### Trailer